# Are Value objects associations possible?

Tags: doctrine-orm

I wonder whether it's possible to have relations between entities and value objects or if a third entity is mandatory as relation target. The purpose could be to flag different kind of entities with a common data structure that has it's own business logic. Any idea ?

Update :

Let's say I have a business object to model SCAP CPE namings :

```
<?php

namespace Scap\Cpe\Naming;

/**
 * Cpe22 represents the naming convention in CPE Naming version 2.2
 * Accepted values are only CPE URIs
 */
class Cpe22
{
    protected $cpe;

    public function __construct($cpe)
    {
        if (! preg_match('/[c][pP][eE]:\/[AHOaho]?(:[A-Za-z0-9\._\-~%]*){0,6}/', $cpe)) {
            throw new InvalidNamingException();
        }
        $this->cpe = $cpe;
    }
}
```

If I want to flag different kind of entities with this VO in a one-to-many way, I can think of 2 different ways :

- Entities are directly related to VOs so that the relation identifiers could be the entities references and the VOs themselves (= key composed from referenced identifier and representative VO fields)
- Entities are related to third entity types, that embed the VOs so that the relation identifiers are those third entities identifiers

So I wonder if only the second option is available or if the first can somehow be implemented.

Comment: Perhaps updating your question with an actual example might help?  By definition a value object has no unique identifier so it is difficult to see how it could participate in other relations.

Answer (score 2):

You should use a [custom mapping type](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/cookbook/custom-mapping-types.html) for things like this. For example, it could look something like this:

```
use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\AbstractPlatform

class Cpe22Type extends Type
{
    public function getSQLDeclaration(array $fieldDeclaration, AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        return $platform->getVarcharTypeDeclarationSQL(array('length' => 250));
    }

    public function convertToPHPVale($value, AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        return new Cpe22($value);
    }

    public function convertToDatabaseValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        return (string) $value;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'cpe22';
    }

    public function requiresSQLCommentHint(AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Obviously, you have to add a `__toString()` method to your `Cpe22` class for this to work.

After registering the type (how you do this depends on your framework, in symfony for example [you do it in config.yml](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/dbal.html#registering-custom-mapping-types)) you can simply map your field as type `cpe22`:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="my_cpe", type="cpe22")
 */
public $myCpe;
```